# Topic Challenge: Space-Colonization

Tags: discussion, tags, challenge

I propose a fortnight-long [space-colonization](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-colonization) topic challenge, which will begin today, August 10th, and finish on August 24th.

Most sci-fi stories feature humans in space.  However, manned missions are currently in decline in the real world.  Machines can often perform the same functions humans can, at a fraction of the cost.  The various motivations for human space travel and colonization frequently put forward in science fiction are a fascinating topic.

I'm excited to see what kinds of questions this community can put forward in regards to [space-colonization](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-colonization)!

EDIT:

The topic challenge is now complete. Thank-you to all participants, and congratulations to Ash, whose question managed to get all three gold topic challenge badges.

Comment: Are we to link our questions in here somehow?

Comment: @dot_Sp0t feel free to do so, but there's no requirement to.  When the topic challenge is finished, I'll collect all the [tag:space-colonization] questions asked while the challenge was going on, and answer the question with a link to them.

Comment: well, I am lazy - So I won't do the work twice if you're gonna do it anyway. Were it my challenge I'd had the querents link it here for my own convenience ;)

Comment: @dot_Sp0T it won't be that difficult to simply click on the tag, go to the "sort by newest" tab, and collect everything from this date on upwards.

Comment: here I try to understand why the decline mentioned above despite of much-discussed exponential developments https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/121607/how-to-establish-the-relationship-between-exponential-development-and-space-expl

Comment: here I try to understand why aliens and humans can get it on and have babies: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/122130/why-might-humans-and-aliens-be-able-to-produce-viable-offspring

Comment: Wow, happy to contribute, I didn't realise the question had been quite that heavily engaged but there you go.

Answer (score 2):

This challenge generated 7 questions and 68 answers, for an average of 9.714 answers per question.

- [If we can have "all the comforts of home" in space why would we settle planets?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/121182/if-we-can-have-all-the-comforts-of-home-in-space-why-would-we-settle-planets) - [Ash](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/40408/ash)

  232 total votes, 30 question votes, 21 answers, 7,769 views

  [image: Vote Hunter (gold badge): over 200 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Pole Position (gold badge): 1st place when sorted by total votes] [image: Idea Generation (gold badge): 20 answers on your question]
- [What could explain why trees only have 12 rings?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/121389/what-could-explain-why-trees-only-have-12-rings) - [cgTag](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/39052/cgtag)

  96 total votes, 13 question votes, 13 answers, 4,146 views

  [image: Vote Seeker (silver badge): over 90 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: So Close And Yet So Far (silver badge): 2nd place when sorted by total votes] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question]
- [Hiding a handful of immortals on a Generation Ship?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/121035/hiding-a-handful-of-immortals-on-a-generation-ship) - [EveryBitHelps](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/21839/everybithelps)

  56 total votes, 10 question votes, 5 answers, 766 views

  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: On The Podium (bronze badge): 3rd place when sorted by total votes] [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [Where on my spaceship can I justify more space for my humans?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/121191/where-on-my-spaceship-can-i-justify-more-space-for-my-humans) - [dot_Sp0T](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2746/dot-sp0t)

  34 total votes, 8 question votes, 15 answers, 671 views

  [image: Vote Novice (bronze badge): over 30 total upvotes on question and answers] [image: Inviting Input (silver badge): 12 answers on your question]
- [Why might humans and aliens be able to produce viable offspring?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/122130/why-might-humans-and-aliens-be-able-to-produce-viable-offspring) - [tox123](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2053/tox123)

  14 total votes, -4 question votes, 6 answers, 163 views

  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [With light years between us, why talk?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/121968/with-light-years-between-us-why-talk) - [Qfwfq](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/43012/qfwfq)

  12 total votes, 1 question votes, 5 answers, 215 views

  [image: Just My 10 Cents (bronze badge): 5 answers on your question]
- [How to establish the relationship between exponential development and space exploration and consequences for future prognosis?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/121607/how-to-establish-the-relationship-between-exponential-development-and-space-expl) - [J. Doe](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/39615/j-doe)

  7 total votes, -2 question votes, 3 answers, 116 views